# Windows 10 ssh, Load Key : Operation not permitted

Tags: windows-10, ssh, private-key

I have a private ssh key generated by PuTTYgen, placed in `C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa`. When I ssh to the remote host, Windows complain:

[image]

Why is the Operation not permitted?

per comment request, the key file permissions (they are the same for the id_rsa folder):

[image]

same thing happens with this:

[image]

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder/file in question?

Comment: @Ramhound, check the updated question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command that you are running is looking for the private key **within the file** `C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa`, **not id_rsa as the directory**

Rename your private key to **id_rsa** and move it to the **C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/** directory. Then run the command you ran, and you should be successful (that is, if your public and private keys have been properly configured).

Comment: thank you, this is what I missed.. totally fixed the problem!

Comment: To add: Both the private *and* the public key have to be named this way:

Filenames: `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`